# Django Template Loaders fail to load templates of my app installed via pip

Tags: python, django

I need help. I have a Django app which I have uploaded to [test.pypi.org](https://test.pypi.org) so that I can install it in my `virtualenv` via `pip`. However, the template loaders fail to look into my app even though it is on my `INSTALLED_APPS` giving me a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error message in debug mode. It looks inside django's template directory and on other installed apps, but skips my app. I do not know what else I am missing. I have looked and searched for a solution, however results return problems related to the django apps, which they are working on locally and not installed on `virtualenv` via `pip` like me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you add your template folder in your app's ` MANIFEST.in` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/)?

Comment: No not yet. I think that is the correct answer. I have not yet gone through that docs. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ok, i am posting an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Python modules and packages are included in the package by default. So to add additional files and folder, we’ll need to create a MANIFEST.in file. Like for this case in our `MANIFEST.in` template folder should include as

```
recursive-include your_app/templates *
```

Comment: Thanks @Shakil. This is quite indeed the answer.

Comment: @RyeSalvador then just accept this as an answer. So that other people will know about it.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: There is 'click' mark in answer section. As you ask the question only you can click that. That means you are accepting this as an answer of your question. Also there is up and down sign. If you click up sign that means you give up vote ( means something that is appreciable ) and also if click down sign you give down vote ( means not relevant answer or something should n't be an answer )

Comment: Ohh okay. Now I see. Thanks again. I need 15 reputations to up vote your answer though.